# Fail to push head on Linked List

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I tried to create a program to add elements to a linked list. The elements consist of name and age. But it fails to add without giving me any error. Could you please show me my mistake?

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "string.h"

#define MAX 9999

struct data {
    char name[MAX];
    int age;
    struct data *next;
};

void pushHead(struct data **head, struct data **tail, char name[], int age) {
    struct data *node = (struct data *)malloc(sizeof(struct data));

    strcpy(node->name, name);
    node->age = age;

    if (*head == NULL) {
        node = *head;
        node = *tail;
        node->next = NULL;
    } else {
        node->next = *head;
        *head = node;
    }
}

void view(struct data *head) {
    struct data *curr = head;
    if (curr == NULL)
        printf("No Data\n");
    else {
        while (curr != NULL) {
            printf("%s(%d)\n", curr->name, curr->age);
            curr = curr->next;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    struct data *head = NULL;
    struct data *tail = NULL;

    pushHead(&head, &tail, "Felix", 19);
    view(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Output : `No Output`

My code is working when I put the head on global scope (by changing all the functions to work globally), but when I try to put the head in main scope it doesn't work.

Comment: `node = *head;` and `node = *tail;`

Comment: Note that the dot `.` and arrow `->` operators bind very tightly indeed and should not be surrounded by spaces on either side.

Comment: The code should not work either with `head` in global scope, but you might have made some other changes that fix the bug.

Comment: You may benefit from looking at the `add` function in [Singly-Linked List](https://pastebin.com/5MPLU4wB) and further from providing both a `head` and `tail` pointer for efficient insertions at the end of the list by using a wrapper struct [Singly-Linked List w/head/tail ptr](https://pastebin.com/R2AewR3A) allowing you to create as many lists as you need.

Answer (score 3):

In `pushHead()`, you are doing:

```
    node = *head;
    node = *tail;
```

this end up assigning `NULL` to `node` pointer because `*head` and `*tail` both are `NULL`. Note that this is a memory leak as your program loose the memory reference which the `node` pointer is holding. Instead, you should do

```
    *head = node;
    *tail = node;
```

Some suggestions:

- For storing `name` in the list node, you are taking buffer of size
  `9999` (`MAX` macro) which is (IMO) very large. I believe, a buffer
  of size `256` is more than enough for this purpose. Or, you can also
  have buffer of exact size required for storing `name` by allocating
  the memory dynamically to it. For this , you have to take a `char *`
  member instead of `char` array for `name` and allocate memory to it
  dynamically based on size of `name` parameter of `pushHead()` and in
  this case, you need to make sure to free it explicitly when deleting
  the list nodes.
- When using `strcpy()` to copy string, make sure that destination
  buffer is large enough to contain the source string to avoid
  overflows.
- Follow good programming practice. Always check `malloc` return and
  ensure to `free` the allocated memory once you are done with it.
- [Do not cast the malloc return.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)
- To include standard library header files use `<>`, i.e. `#include "stdio.h"` -> `#include <stdio.h>`, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename).